# ChessBoard Game

Tags: chessboard

How can I beat this stage? 
Rules:

1. You can only move a piece if  it's going to eliminate another piece.
2. Capture the chess pieces until one piece only is left .
3. Move the chess piece one at a time.

[image]

Comment: I have no idea whether the rules allow this solution. Assume that the pawn is moving from top to bottom. Have the knight take the bishop and the righthand rook. The remaining then takes the queen. Finally, the pawn, which has reached the far rank from its point of view, is promoted to queen and takes the rook and then the knight.

Comment: It doesn't work! I think there is an error in the game itself

Comment: It works; I just don’t know whether the rules allow one to assume that the pawn is moving from top to bottom and can therefore be promoted.

Comment: I mean I just tried it but the game is not made like that.It didn't promote my pawn so the stage isn't cleared yet

Comment: Ah, I see; I didn’t realize that the game was actually implemented, rather than being just a set of rules.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, it sounds like this is a puzzle that you can play online, but as far as I can see, it's just an image with no interactivity.

In any case, I'm assuming the pawn is moving from bottom to top, as usual.

1. R (on the right) xN
2. PxR
3. PxQ
4. RxP
5. RxB

Comment: Thanks. I am just wondering if there is a certain technique I can do to be able to solve these kind of puzzles or by just trial and error

Comment: I don't know of any simple algorithm, but there are better approaches than just trial and error -- you can analyze the placement of the pieces. For example, the bishop in the problem can't capture any pieces (since before the bishop is captured, the other pieces have to remain on black squares, but the bishop can only move to white squares).